# Angular set the title in URL instead id

Tags: angular

I have a route in my angular page as:

```
{
  path: 'topics/:id',
  component: TopicsComponent,
},
```

I absolutely need the :id param to retrieve the topic.

But instead `http://myapp.com/topics/123` I want `http://myapp.com/topics/the-title-of-the-topic`.

I cannot get topic by Title so I need the id, I don't know how can I do to change the url ? I don't want the id in the url.

I've made some search but I don't find anything.

If you can give me link / direct help, thanks in advance

Comment: pass data in navigationExtra https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras if you don't want to show in URL

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

Setup your routing like:

- `topics/:id/:title`
- `topics/:title/:id` or similar variants.

This way you should have access to both. If this gives you problems, you could go for a convention and add the `ID` to your `titleUrl` and parse it from there. This way you could do `topics/:topicUrl` that is made out of `:title-:id`, you can write a parser to take the `topicUrl` and make an `id` and `title` out of that.

Comment: Ok so there is no way to remove the ID in the url if the ID is in the params ?

Comment: If you need the ID as you've said multiple times, I'm afraid not. Especially if you want the page to be able to F5 after; you need it as part of the state in the URL. You can hide it nicely and be smart about it, but you'll need to add it if you want it to be unique.

Comment: Medium.com and other sites do this too. :-) They add it to the end of the title.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score -1):

you can directly give the name of string instead of id Like:

```
{
 path: 'topics/:title',
...
}
```

Comment: Nope I cannot. I cannot retrieve the topic with the title because the title is not unique in database. I absolutely need the ID.

Comment: Then you may pass id in encrypted form

Comment: What do You mean ? Can You give me a link or something ?

Comment: You can pass id in encrypted from of id from backend and show it to url. Suppose you are using PHP in backend then you may use Crypt::encrypt($id)